# jQuery Data-call back ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I have implemented the [automatically bind to button recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible), However I am a bit confused as how I am to handle the `data-call` back into my current block oh `jQuery`

**In the docs that I have linked to above it has:**

```
<script>
function onSubmit(token) {
 document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
}
</script>
```

**Button:**

```
<div class="infusion-submit">
    <input class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="someKey" data-callback='onSubmit' data-callback='onSubmit' type="submit" value="Request Itinerary" />
</div>
```

**jQuery Block:**

```
  $('#foodForm').submit(function(e) { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                if (response.length > 0) {
                    $('#foodFormResponse').html(response); // update the DIV
                } else {
                    window.location.href = 'https://URl.com/private/thank-you/';
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

**Update:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function foodFormSubmit(){
    $("#foodForm").submit();
  }

     $('#foodForm').submit(function(e) { // catch the form's submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    if (response.length > 0) {
                        $('#foodFormResponse').html(response); // update the DIV
                    } else {
                        window.location.href = 'https://url.com/private/thank-you/';
                    }
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery `submit()` method rather than calling the native DOM method.

```
function onSubmit() {
    $("#demo-form").submit();
}
```

Then it will call the jQuery handler that you bound.

Comment: Thanks so after the .submit(); I just run the normal AJAX?

Comment: This will run the AJAX code that you put in `$("#demo-form").submit(...)`

Comment: So instead of using the wrap of ` $('#foodForm').submit(function(e) ` I wrap the code in .submit(datahere?);?

Comment: No, leave that code as it is. This function will run it.

Comment: Thanks,  I have updated my question with my code,  I am getting an error of: ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: foodFormSubmit

Comment: The function definition shouldn't be inside `$(document).ready()`, it needs to be called from the global scope.